# Инструмент для оптимизации css и js

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то инструмент, который позволит проанализировать css/js файл и разобьет его на 2 файла. Чтобы файл с критическим кодом, который будет задействован на странице, подключить в шапке, а второй в футере, например, который нужен не сразу для модальных окон и т.д. Похожий инструмент содержит консоль в хроме. Красным неиспользуемый страницей код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Человек которой в этом разбирается - вот этот инструмент.